# C - Architecture independent function call interposition

Tags: c, assembly

I'm writing a piece of code where I have a function pointer that gets invoked. What I'd like to do is interpose on this function call to do something, and then invoke anotherfunction call with the same arguments. I wonder if there is some way to do this without having to write assembly for each architecture I'm targeting. Perhaps there are some GCC tricks?

As an example I call my function pointer and it invokes

```
foo (/*arguments*/) {
  do_something...
  bar(/*same arguments*/);
}
```

In assembly this is fairly easy. At least in x86 I just make sure that my stack pointer is reset to the beginning of my stack frame and jump to function bar (not call).

EDIT: Perhaps the example isn't clear. The user expects to be calling function bar but instead I have redirected it to function foo (I don't know what arguments bar takes). I want to do something in foo before calling bar with the same arguments that were passed on. In this way, whatever I'm doing in foo is transparent to the user who thinks they just called bar.

Comment: Are variadic functions an option?

Comment: Not sure how that would help, I can wrap the arguments up into a va_list but I need to unwrap them before sending or else its a different argument lay out

Comment: GCC will do tail calls.  If you write `return bar(same args)` you will see it end in `jmp`.  I'm pretty sure it will do it even if there are fewer args, so you may be able to `return bar()` and trust your args being undisturbed.  Not something I'd want to rely on for a shipping product...

Comment: Can you point me to anywhere in GCC's documentation? This doesn't seem like expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into gcc option `-finstrument-functions`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the functions I would be instrumenting at compile time and I want to instrument functions differently.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what the the gcc specific [___builtin_apply_args](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC67___builtin_apply_args) is for. It's an intristic that captures the passed in argument, and you can call another function with those arguments using __builtin_apply

Comment: This won't work because I don't know the amount of arguments passed. If you look at __builtin_apply, I have to pass a size value.

Answer (score 1):

[libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) does all (or at least most) of what you need for source-level interposing.

Another option is to use dynamic binary instrumentation tools like [DynamoRIO](http://dynamorio.org/) or [Pin](http://www.pintool.org/).

Comment: These solutions all look much heavier weight than what I want. The DBI solutions for sure I don't want because of the performance hits. Additionally I cannot depend on system libraries.

Comment: I'm quite sure libffi can be linked statically. And I think you should actually try how much "weight" or performance hit they add before dismissing. Of course, you can just as well invent your own wheel.

Comment: I've used both DynamoRIO and Pin before, they aren't suitable for this project. libffi includes system libraries I don't have in my environment (and shouldn't need).

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a global function pointer variable that is used as a look-up for pre-binding the two function calls to one another.  For instance,

```
typedef void (*bar_type)(int arg1, int arg2);
bar_type function_ptr; //a global function pointer used for binding

//create a bar_type function that is our "actual" function call
void __bar(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    //do something else
}

//create a bar_type function called "foo" that is bound to calling whatever
//function is being pointed to by function_ptr
void foo(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    //do something
    function_ptr(arg1, arg2); //"foo" now calls "__bar"
}

bar_type transform_func(bar_type func_call, bar_type int_call)
{
    function_ptr = func_call; //set the global function ptr variable
    return int_call;
}

//create your function pointer bar that will call "foo" before calling "__bar"
bar_type bar = transform_func(__bar, foo);

//later on in your code
bar(3, 4); //this will call foo() which will then call __bar() internally
```

You could also with this approach create a macro that for the user where you could define `bar` as a macro that looks like

```
#define bar(arg1, arg2) (*(transform_func(__bar, foo)))(arg1, arg2);
```

Hopefully this isn't too kludgy ... there is definitely a performance hit from what could be done with assembly, but using the global function pointer would be a way to re-bind a function call.

Comment: This won't work because I don't know the type "bar_type." Bar could be any function with any number of arguments. If I knew the type then this is really a non-issue since I could just copy the arguments in as you've done.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying that, sorry to hear this solution won't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a function-like macro to implement "do something" in the context of the calling function, and then do a normal call to the function pointer? (Yes, standard disclaimers about macros, esp. function-like macros apply...)

For example something like:

```
#define CALL_FUNC(fp,ARG1,ARG2) do {<do something>;fp(ARG1,ARG2);} while (0)
```

And then in the application, replace where you de-reference the function pointer with the macro.

It's not clear to me from the original question if `foo` or `bar` is the function called through the function pointer, so you might need to adjust the macro, but the general approach stays the same.